# Redux: No reducer provided for key

Tags: redux

I tried to make a state shape like this

```
entities: {
    selectedPost: 0,
    posts: {
      byId: {},
      allIds: []
    }
}
```

## 1

and I used combineReducers, but I got " No reducer provided for key posts".

```
export const entitiesReducer = combineReducers({
  selectedPost: selectedPost,
  posts: postsReducer
});
const postsReducer = combineReducers({
  byId: postsById,
  allIds: allPosts
});
```

## 2

so I tried this way, and it works, but I cant understand what's the difference

```
export const entitiesReducer = combineReducers({
  selectedPost: selectedPost,
  posts: combineReducers({
    byId: postsById,
    allIds: allPosts
  })
});
```

## 3

I also tried this. It works too

```
export const entitiesReducer = combineReducers({
  selectedPost: selectedPost,
  posts: postsReducer
});

function postsReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return {
        byId: postsById(state.byId, action),
        allIds: allPosts(state.allIds, action)
      };
  }
}
```

what mistake I made in the first case?
thanks

Comment: can you replace the order of your combined reducers?

place postsReducer  at first

Comment: `combineReducers` associates state property to reducer function of **the same name** if you attempt to change the store variable that doesn't have reducer with corresponding name, you run into such kind of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace the order of your combined reducers, place postsReducer at first